# How do you make a function that has to do a query on the firebase database and return the value of the query as an int?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We are currently making an iOS app and with firebase as its database. Please find below our code.

```
static func getTilesPerRow () -> Int{

    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    guard let uid = user?.uid else {
        return -2
    }
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    let userRef = ref.child("user").child(uid)

    var num = -1

    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "observer")

    userRef.child("tilesPerRow").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        print("now inside the observe thing------------------")
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        num = snapshot.value as? Int ?? 0
        print("just updated the number to ", num)
        print("the snapshot is ", snapshot)
        print("the value is ", value)
        print("the real value is", snapshot.value)
        print("just making sure, the number that was set is ", num)

    }) { (error) in
        print("there was an error!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    print("about to return from the function ", num)
    return num
}
```

Currently while running this code, we get the following output.

```
about to return from the function  -1
now inside the observe thing------------------
just updated the number to  5
the snapshot is  Snap (tilesPerRow) 5
the value is  nil
the real value is Optional(5)
just making sure, the number that was set is  5
```

Our expected output is:

```
now inside the observe thing------------------
just updated the number to  5
the snapshot is  Snap (tilesPerRow) 5
the value is  nil
the real value is Optional(5)
just making sure, the number that was set is  5
about to return from the function  5
```

The problem here is that we are trying to grab the value of what the query has found, but because .observe() is asynchronous, the function finishes before .observe() updates the value of num. How do we return the correct value?

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to try to make an asynchronous operation into a blocking synchronous function.  That will make your app perform poorly.  The APIs for mobile development are async for a reason: https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93

Comment: The short answer is "You don't." You should make getTilesPerRow take  a completion handler that gets called once the value is available.

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

To get the asynchronous operation result you use blocks.

```
static func getTilesPerRow (@escaping completion: (Int?)->Void ) {

    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    guard let uid = user?.uid else {
        completion(nil)
    }
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    let userRef = ref.child("user").child(uid)

    userRef.child("tilesPerRow").observeSingleEvent(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        print("now inside the observe thing------------------")
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let num = snapshot.value as? Int ?? 0
        completion(num)

    }) { (error) in
        print("there was an error!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        completion(nil)
    }
}
```

When the results are ready you will get notified through the block. Upon success you get the actual `num` you are looking for or `nil` upon any error occurred.

Even you can distinguish that what sort of error occurred by adding extra parameter on your parameter list in `completion` block.

You also could use protocol, but thats require more knowledge like, in which class this code reside, who is the caller this sort of things. Set the protocol target to the caller, and upon completion called method will fire different protocol method based on the error or successful case occurred.

Happy coding.

Comment: What's the purpose of *queue* here? Firebase is asynchronous; UI calls within the closure are performed on the main thread and the closure will complete when the data is available from Firebase. Also, this code is using .value so it's kind of redundant; .value leaves an observer on the node in question so any time there's a change in the data the code within the closure would be called. It would probably be better to use .observeSingleEvent since it's being treated more as a function that returns a value. Other than that, good answer.